# Switch to root using SSH key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, root

I recently disabled Root SSH login but I forgot to add sudo access for my user account. I am trying to switch back into root using

```
su root
```

But, it is asking for a password (instead of the private SSH key). How can I switch to root using my root private key? I cannot log-in since I have disabled that feature.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have `pam` configured to accept SSH keys? If not, you're going to have to boot into a recovery system.

Comment: @Panki, thanks. I am not sure if I have it on, what would I have to do if it was enabled?

Comment: Do you have physical access to the system?

Comment: Or a root shell on the web interface of your provider.

Comment: you can try `ssh root@localhost -i <keyfile>` if you have a key for the root user (which is a bad way to set things up, generally speaking).

Comment: If you have console access (most Cloud Providers do offer VNC console), you can login, or simply reboot system into recovery mode